# Is AOP supported in Helidon MP?

Tags: aop, spring-aop, helidon

Like Spring framework, I want to create a Pointcut to execute some logic before executing the method. Is it possible to do that in Helidon MP?

```java
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
private void anyPublicOperation(String input) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Helidon MP, like all [MicroProfile](https://microprofile.io/) implementations, is centered around [CDI](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/), which offers, for this purpose, [interceptors](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#interceptors) and [decorators](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#decorators).

Answer (score 0):

I have already done that using `Interceptor`. Thanks!
Here is the example:

- Creating a custom annotation with `@InterceptorBinding`

```java
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SoapSecure {
  String tokenParam() default "token";
}
```

- Creating the interceptor

```java
@Priority(1)
@Interceptor
@SoapSecure
@Slf4j
public class SoapAuthenticationInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private AuthService authService;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object validateToken(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        Method method = invocationContext.getMethod();
        log.info("Validate the token from SOAP APIs: " + method.getName());

        String tokenParam = method
                .getAnnotation(SoapSecure.class)
                .tokenParam();

        Parameter[] params = method.getParameters();
        String accessToken = null;
        for (Parameter p : params) {
            if (p.getName().equals(tokenParam)) {
                // validate the access token
                authService.validateAccessToken(Objects.toString(method.invoke(p)));
            }
        }

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```java
 @SoapSecure
 public boolean test(String token){}
```